# Stop webpage from waiting for cancelled XHR requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm working on a Django project and the Javascript for one of my pages makes some XHR requests that can take a while to complete. If the user goes to this page, they have to wait for these requests to finish before the site lets them go to another page.

I've been trying to have the page cancel these requests when clicking to another page, but even if the requests cancel the page still waits quite a while before changing URLs. This is how my requests are structured.

```
const controller = new AbortController()
const signal = controller.signal

let get_salesperson_sales = async() => {
    return await fetch(`/reports/salesperson-sales/${fromDate && toDate ? `from_date=${fromDate}&to_date=${toDate}` : ''}`, { signal })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        document.getElementById('total_rep_sales').innerText = '$'+Number(response.total_sales.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString()
        return response
    })
    .catch(error => {
        if (error.name === 'AbortError') console.log('Salesperson sales fetch was aborted.')
        else errorMessage.innerHTML += '<p>Error getting sales by rep: '+error.responseJSON ? error.responseJSON.details : 'Unexpected error'+'</p>'
    })
}
```

There are 4 of these functions in total that I call with Promise.allSettled(). At the bottom of the page, I bind a couple functions to abort the requests.

```
$('#date-filter').submit(() => {
    // Stop loading current report before submitting
    controller.abort()
    return true
})
$(window).bind('beforeunload', () => {
    controller.abort()
})
```

The requests cancel successfully, I can see both in the Network tab of my browser and because my console logs show up in the console, but for some reason the page continues to wait after the requests are cancelled.

The part that's really tripping me up is that, while this happens in my production build, the page seems to change immediately upon cancelling requests when I run the project on localhost. The only major configuration difference between the web app in both builds is that Django's DEBUG is True in the local build and False in the production build. I've tried 4 different methods of cancelling requests and 2 different kinds of request ($.ajax and fetch), each time successfully cancelling the requests and running into this problem.

What could possibly be causing this issue and how can I force my page to change immediately instead of waiting like this?

Comment: Remove the `async` from the function and the `await` from the `fetch()` call. Simply return the Promise from `fetch()`. Eventhough the promise rejected and printed your error message in the console, you still have the outstanding, unsettled, Promise from the `async` function. Besides, the `async/await` makes no sense there.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't considered an issue with outstanding promises. There were some other promises in my code that were necessary to wait for, so clean up was a little more complex than just removing async/await, but I've got it working now!

Comment: Also, the async/await is a relic from an older version of the code where it was necessary. Just didn't bother to remove it because I didn't think it was causing a problem.

Comment: I lied, it's not actually working. It was just working on local again because the API calls are faster from our testing sites. I'm seeing console logs showing that all of my promises are rejecting successfully, but it still waits to load before switching pages.